# Viewing XAML from a compiled DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, disassembly

I'm trying to develop a Visual Studio 2010 extension and it would be a lot easier if I could see what the Visual Studio XAML looks like. I used Reflector and the BAML disassembler but that didn't seem to give me what I want. The URI for the XAML file I'm looking for is:

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal;component/mainwindow/mainwindow.xaml`

The DLL that this was found in was `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll`. Does this mean there should be a resource by that name? I don't see one in Reflector at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.resources.dll`.  That seems to contain the BAML resources.